# mCustomScrollbar move the scrollbar to the right

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I would like to move a little bit the scroll bar to the right from mCustomScrollbar.

Default:

[image]

Wished result:

[image]

I initialise it like that:

```
$(".framed-content").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme: "dark-2",
    scrollButtons:{ enable: true },
});
```

If I had the option `scrollbarPosition: "string"` it's too much on the right, outside of the box.

Is there any way from the given options of this jQuery plugin? http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of a padding in the framed-content div. I removed it and put the padding in the div inside the framed-content div:

```
       <div class="framed-content" style="height:274px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;">
           <div style="padding:20px;height:400px;">
              List of frames...
           </div>
       </div>
```